# Realtek RTL8852AE issue on HP 15s-eq2028ur Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, xubuntu, hp, rtl

I have issue with wifi connection on my laptop. I followed other same topics but my issue is actualy.

After this `$ sudo lspci -k -nn | grep -A 3 -i net` I have got

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:a85a]
    DeviceName: Realtek Wireless LAN + BT
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:88e2]
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: KIOXIA Corporation Device [1e0f:0001]
```

After `sudo modprobe rtw89pci` and then `sudo dmesg | grep rtw`
I have got

```
[    2.980960] rtw89core: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    2.981072] rtw89core: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not certain it will help, I found building and installing a driver from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89 worked on my HP 14" laptop running Linux Mint 20.1 (based on Ubuntu 20.04 code infrastructure).

JN

Comment: It works for me! Thank's! I had one problem of this. There wasn't rtw89 directory but I created it manualy.

Comment: I should add that I've since found that I don't get a proper network printer installation to my Brother HL2270DW. I tried a USB ethernet (wired - fine), and a TP-Link TL-WN321G USB wifi dongle also OK, but a (new, tiny) TP-Link WN725N clobbered all wifi and popped up some messages that wifi disabled because of some problem with Realtek Renoir GPP Bridge. It seems there's a fight between internal Realtek and USB one. I suspect that I may have to play around quite a bit with printer settings and/or some of the options in rtw89 -- assuming it is running correctly for all aspects of the protocol.

Comment: After core update driver not working again. For fix it driver has to install again.

Comment: Yes. I found I had to reinstall after kernel updated too. Not a big deal, but an annoyance.

Comment: Also found that I have to use direct IP4 number to get to printer etc. still. I suspect there are still a few features lacking in the rtw89 driver.